# UDP send behaviour after connect()

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <errno.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <sys/socket.h>  
#include <netinet/in.h>  
#include <arpa/inet.h>  

int main()  
{    
    struct sockaddr_in addr;  
    int fd, cnt,ret;  
    char ch = 'y',msg[] ="How are you";  

    if ((fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0)) < 0) {  
        printf("Error: socket");  
        exit(1);  
    }
    printf("\nDone socket\n");  

    /* set up destination address */  
    memset(&addr,0,sizeof(addr));  
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;  
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("128.88.143.113");  
    addr.sin_port=htons(9090);  

    ret=connect(fd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr));  
    perror("Connect:");  

    while(ch == 'y'){  
        cnt =  send(fd,msg,sizeof(msg),0);  
        if(cnt < 0)  
        perror("send:");  
        printf("\nNumber of bytes sent = %d , \n",cnt);  
        printf("Continue (y/n)\n");  
        scanf(" %c",&ch);  

     }

     return 0;  
}
```

The above code is compiled to run on a Linux machine.

Assume that the above code sends data to a machine at IP address `128.88.143.113`. No UDP socket is bound to port `9090` at `128.88.143.113`.

In the `while` loop, the first call to `send()` succeeds(the packet actually goes out on the wire; checked it using `trace`) and the second `send()` fails with `Connection refused`. The `third send()` succeeds and the forth fails and so on.

I suspect that after first `send()` the stack receives an ICMP error message(seen in `tcpdump` on the Linux machine) which is saved in the socket structure. The second `send()` fails upon seeing this error and no packet is actually sent out. The second `send()` also clears the error in the socket structure. Therefore the third `send()` succeeds and the forth fails and so on.

Questions:

1. Is this assumption correct?
2. What should be the correct behavior? Is there any RFC standard defining such behavior?
3. Since UDP does not maintain any connection state, shouldn't every `send()` succeed?

Comment: I see similar behaviour on an arch linux machine when sending over an alias interface. Was this resolved?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [linux man page for udp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html):

> All fatal errors will be passed to the
>   user as an error return even when the
>   socket is not connected. This includes
>   asynchronous errors received from the
>   network. You may get an error for an
>   earlier packet that was sent on the
>   same socket. This behaviour differs
>   from many other BSD socket
>   implementations which don't pass any
>   errors unless the socket is connected.
>   Linux's behaviour is mandated by [RFC 1122](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1122.txt).

Specifically the [RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1122.txt) (4.1.3.3) states:

> UDP MUST pass to the application layer all ICMP error
>   messages that it receives from the IP layer.  Conceptually
>   at least, this may be accomplished with an upcall to the
>   ERROR_REPORT routine

Answer (score 3):

Your hypothesis is correct.  The Linux udp(7) man page describes the situation thus:

> All  fatal  errors  will  be  passed 
>   to the user as an error return even
>   when the socket is not connected. 
>   This includes asynchronous errors
>   received from the network.  You may
>   get an error for an earlier packet
>   that was sent on the same socket.
>   This behavior differs from many other
>   BSD socket implementations which don't
>   pass any errors unless the socket is
>   connected.  Linux's behavior is
>   mandated by [RFC 1122](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1122.txt).
>
> When the `IP_RECVERR` option is
>   enabled all errors are stored in the
>   socket error queue and can be received
>   by `recvmsg(2)` with the
>   `MSG_ERRQUEUE` flag set.

Answer (score 2):

It would be interesting to compare the equivalent code using `sendto()` rather than `connect()` and `send()`.

Does the code shown fail in the same way if you leave a period of time between each send, i.e. is the ICMP error state being kept in the socket for a period of time, or would it still fail the second `send()` if you left it, say, an hour?

I expect that your assumption is correct, the network stack is trying to be clever. There's no other point when it could return 'connection refused' as nothing is sent when the `connect()` call is issued it simply stores the address given so that the socket is 'logically' connected and calls to `send()` can then work.

Answer (score 1):

To start at the other end, if you connect a UDP socket you can collect errors on the next send. If you don't want that, don't connect!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; and the is due to the fact that the udp message queue is filled if nobody is listening and emptying the queue.