# ICMP Host-Unreachable

Tags: c, sockets, port, icmp

How do I know if I got an ICMP Host Unreachable after trying to send some data to a UDP port ? I want to check for opened UDP ports on a machine.

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc792.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html) - you'll get an error on the second send, see more about [connected UDP sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397195/udp-send-behaviour-after-connect).